# Type cast array elements in for loop

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift, casting

In a delegate method, I get back a ‘results’ array of a custom object type, and I want to loop through the array elements. 
I do the following now, and this works

```
for result in results {
    if result is XYZClass {     
        //This Works!    
    }
}
```

Is there a way to type cast the objects in the for-loop to avoid writing two lines? Does swift permit this? Used to get this done fairly easily in Objective - C

```
for (XYZClass *result in results) {

}
```

However, I have not been successful in Swift. I’ve tried explicit-cast with no luck.

```
for result as XYZClass in results {
    //ERROR: Expected ‘;’ in ‘for’ statements
}

for result:AGSGPParameterValue in results {
    /* ERROR: This prompts down cast as 
    for result:AGSGPParameterValue in results as AGSGPParameterValue { }
    which in turn errors again “Type XYZClass does not conform to Sequence Type”
*/
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
for result in results as [XYZClass] {
    // Do stuff to result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are using the for loop it may be instead preferable to use `compactMap` (or `flatMap` if you are before Swift 4.1) to map your objects into a new array:

```
let onlyXyzResults: [XYZClass] = results.compactMap { $0 as? XYZClass }
```

Now you have an array XYZClass objects only, with all other object types removed.